# We would like to present a message to our users upon successful login to update their records. Any ideas why code isn't working?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

Recently, our database crashed and we are left with spreadsheet record of our users.

We imported the data from the spreadsheet to our Users table.

Since there are several users numbering well over 3 thousand, we would like to put out a message in bold text and with yellow text color on our home page so that as soon as a user logs in, if any of his/her records are blank or null, sh/he would see this advising her to go to his/her profile page and update his/her personal records.

After the user's record has been updated, this message won't display any longer.

I am sure not what I am doing wrong but the code below is not working.

I keep getting the error that nameTB is used before being assigned a value. I am sure it will be the same for the rest.

Any ideas what I need to do to get it to work?

```
      If Not IsPostBack Then
          If Session("username") Is Nothing Then
              ' Redirect user to login before doing anything else
              Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx?redirect=default.aspx")
          Else
              Dim myConnectionString As [String] = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString
              Dim myConnection As New SqlConnection(myConnectionString)
              Dim nameTB As String
              Dim AddressTB As String
              Dim emailTB As String
              Dim phoneTB As String
              Dim PrecinctTB As String
              Dim PositionTB As String
              Try
                  myConnection.Open()

                  '*
                  '                         * Find personal info 
                  '                         

                  Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand("Select l.FullName,l.address,l.Phone_nbr,l.email,l.precinct,p.position_title  from Users l inner join Posts p on l.positionId = p.positionId and l.username = @username and l.email=@email", myConnection)
                  cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Session("username"))
                  cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Session("UserId"))
                  Dim dr2 As SqlDataReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader()
                  If dr2.Read() Then
                      nameTB = dr2("FullName").ToString()
                      AddressTB = dr2("address").ToString()
                      phoneTB = dr2("phone_nbr").ToString()
                      emailTB = dr2("email").ToString()
                      PrecinctTB = dr2("precinct").ToString()
                      PositionTB = dr2("Position_title").ToString()
                  End If
                  If nameTB ="" or AddressTB ="" or phoneTB ="" or phoneTB is null or PrecinctTB = "" or PositionTB = "" Then
                  lblMessage.Text = " Please update your profile"
                  else
                  End If
            'Check to see if any field is blank or null


                  dr2.Close()

              Catch ex As SqlException
                  Response.Write("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>alert('" + ex.Message + "')</SCRIPT>")
              Finally
                  myConnection.Close()
              End Try
          End If
End If
```

Comment: Hmmm.  Having "IsPostBack" and "SqlConnection" in the same code file.  You may want to read this oldie but goodie.   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ee817644%28pandp.10%29.aspx

Comment: Can you please give this a reasonable title and include actual question and information in the body of the question.

Comment: What has this todo with C#..?

Comment: Jesus, hideous code. Thank heavens for MVC!

Comment: Remove your c# tag - us c#ers wont be very useful with vb.net!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your

```
If nameTB = "" or AddressTB = "" or phoneTB = "" or phoneTB is null or PrecinctTB = "" or PositionTB = "" Then
```

line is using nameTB before nameTB has potentially been assigned a value.  You are only assigning nameTB a value inside your `If dr2.Read() Then` block.
If the code does not go inside that block, your strings will not have been assigned a value.

Comment: Guys, thanks for your posts. I am only going to focus on the positive feedbacks. I definitely don't mind the criticisms; it comes with the territory as long as you do so with some helpful feedbacks. For that, I am grateful to you Golden and GranadaCoder. Golden, after making the changes you recommended, the code works as expected for us. Thanks a lot